# NServiceBus v5 Circuit Breaker

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus, nservicebus5

We have recently upgraded our NServiceBus project from version 4 to version 5. We are using NHibernate for data storage to an SQL server database. Since the upgrade we have started to encounter an error around connection timeouts and the TimeoutEntity table. The NServiceBus services run fine for a while - at least a couple of hours and then they stop.

When investigating the cause of this it seems to be down to polling query to the TimeoutEntity table - the query is done every minute and if the query takes more than 2 seconds to complete an error is raised and CriticalError.Raise is called - this causes the NServiceBus to stop the service.

One route of investigation is to find out of the cause of the timeouts, but we would also like to know why this functionality was changed - in the previous version of NServiceBus, Logger.Warn was called rather than CriticalError.Raise. Would anybody know why this change was made in NServiceBus 5 and what we can do to mitigate it?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the time to wait before raising a critical error, see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/critical-exception-for-timeout-outages on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define your own critical error action by using

```
config.DefineCriticalErrorAction((message, exception) => {
     <do something here>
});
```